# How to solve the "AttributeError: module 'xmltodict' has no attribute 'parse'".?

Tags: python, attributeerror

In a python program I have imported few modules and I am trying to run pre defined python file xmltodict where 'parse' function was defined. But it is showing me that "AttributeError: module 'xmltodict' has no attribute 'parse'".

I have included the xmltodict.py file in the same working directory of my working Jupyter notebook. But still it is showing me the same.

Please do help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please post your code and your directory structure too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue?
What pip package have you installed? Perhaps the following?
https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/master/xmltodict.py

How are you importing the package into your Jupyter environment?

How are you accessing `xmltodict.parse()`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on AWS Lambda function and I resolved that problem **by extracting** everything from main **xmltodict folder** in the root directory. Try with that and if your problem still exist, post your project directory here.